# Return value of overloaded <<

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct info {
    info(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const info &myinfo){
    out << myinfo.x << "  " << myinfo.y;
    return cout;
}

int main() {
    info a(1,2);
    info b(3,4);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

The output of the above program seems fine even with the incorrect overload of `operator <<`.

Can anyone tell me what is the effect of this overloading problem? I know the overloading function should return `out` instead of `cout`, but how does the above version behave?

Comment: not related to operator overloading, but you have a bug in constructor:

    struct info {
        info(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}  // here a changed to x, b changed to y
        int x;
        int y;
     };

Answer (score 6):

In this case, since you are passing in `std::cout` to the overloaded `operator<<`, there is no difference in behavior. Generally, though, you would cause the `" " << b << std::endl` to get sent to `std:cout`, while your `a` would go to whatever you passed in.

For example:

```
info a(1,2);
info b(3,4);
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << a << " " << b << std::endl;
```

would cause `a` to go to `ss`.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in this situation, obviously, because the target stream is `cout`.  It will break in other situations.

Comment: @user1494533: Any time you're not streaming to `cout`!  Try using `cerr` or a `std::stringstream` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It just *happens* to work here, because `out` and `cout` refers to the same object.